# Infix to Postfix Python: IndexError: pop from empty list.Doesnt Work on Digits more than one

Tags: python, stack

My code:

```
from StackClass import Stack


def postfixEval(postfix):
    os = Stack()

    tokenList = postfix

    for token in tokenList:
        if token in "0123456789":
            os.push(int(token))
        else:
            op2 = os.pop()
            op1 = os.pop()
            result = doMath(token,op1,op2)
            os.push(result)
    return os.pop()

def doMath(op, op1, op2):
    if op == "*":
        return op1 * op2
    elif op == "/":
        return op1 / op2
    elif op == "+":
        return op1 + op2
    else:
        return op1 - op2



def pres(p):
    if p is '(':
        return 0
    elif p is '+' or '-':
        return 1
    elif p is '*' or '/':
        return 2
    else:
        return 99

def read(p):
    if p is '(':
        return left
    elif p is ')':
        return right
    elif p is '+' or p is '-' or p is '*' or p is '%' or p is '/':
        return operator
    elif p is ' ':
        return empty    
    else :
        return operand                          




def infixtopostfix(infixexp):

    for i in infixexp :
        type = read(i)
        if type is left :
            outlst.append(i)
        elif type is right :
            next = outlst.pop()
            while next is not '(':
                postfix.append(next)
                next = outlst.pop()
        elif type is operand:
            postfix.append(i)
        elif type is operator:
            p = pres(i)
            while len(outlst) is not 0 and p <= pres(outlst[-1]) :
                postfix.append(outlst.pop())
            outlst.append(i)
        elif type is empty:
            continue

    while len(outlst) > 0 :
        postfix.append(outlst.pop())
    return " ".join(postfix)












#MAIN PROGRAM


while True:



    postfix = []
    outlst = []
    operator = -10
    operand = -20
    left = -30
    right = -40
    empty = -50


    infixexp = raw_input("\nEnter the infix notation : ")
    ifx = infixexp.split()
    showpfx = infixtopostfix(ifx)

    print "\nIt's postfix notation is \n"
    print(showpfx) 

    print "\nThe answer to the postfix notation is: \n"
    pfx = showpfx.split()
    print postfixEval(pfx)  



    choice = raw_input("\nDo you want to continue?<1-Yes/0-No>: ")

    if choice == '0':
        break
```

This works on ( 1 + 3 ) * 5 but gives this error on ( 500 + 500 ) * 1000 :

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "practice.py", line 117, in
> <module>
>     print postfixEval(pfx)   File "practice.py", line 13, in postfixEval
>     op2 = os.pop()   File "C:\Python27\StackClass.py", line 16, in pop
>     return self.items.pop() IndexError: pop from empty list
```

After return postfix value, I split it again and then inserted it on the evaluation function. It does work on 1 digit numbers but not on three digit ones. Any idea whats wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `elif p is '+' or '-':` is an issue. And stop using `is` where you should use `==`

Comment: @Khristos

I only used the basic stack implementation. Any idea why this doesn't allow more than one digit? I think its in this expression: `if token in "0123456789":` How do I say that if token is any digit?

Comment: `if token.isdigit()`. else it only matches substrings of `0123456789`

Comment: @Rekt `if token in "0123456789"` will return True for tokens like 01 , 12 ,34 (consective digits), but not 35, etc

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ohhhh there was a built-in, thanks Jean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if token in "0123456789":
```

that matches only substrings of `"0123456789"`, for instance single digits, `12`, `789` ... The actual way of checking for a real positive integer would be:

```
if token.isdigits():
```

(if you have the negative numbers handled already that is, else try to convert to integer and catch the `ValueError`)

BIG Aside: While I'm at it, I'd better tell you the next things that will fail in your code:

`is` is comparing *references*. While string interning works well with short strings, I wouldn't rely on that. Use `==` instead.

There is another serious issue in `pres`:

```
elif p is '+' or '-':
```

is checking if `p` is `+`, but if it isn't it tests if `-` is "truthy", which is ... always. So your condition is always true.

Rewrite it with `in` on strings:

```
def pres(p):
    if p == '(':
        return 0
    elif p in '+-':
        return 1
    elif p in '*/':
        return 2
    else:
        return 99
```

and get rid of all the `is` tests in favor of `==`. That will avoid surprises (the exception being the singleton objects like `None` where `is` is idiomatic)

Note: in `read` you were correct (except for the `is` part):

```
elif p is '+' or p is '-' or p is '*' or p is '%' or p is '/':
```

but of course it's still shorter and better to write it:

```
elif p in '+-*%/':
```